# Any SMO Library for .NET?

Tags: c#, database, backup

Anyone knows any library for SQL Server database backup and restore for .NET?

This actually is needed to avoid writing one new. There is so many people out there giving their libraries, but i found it strange i couldn't came up with googling anything related.

Comment: Is there some reason you don't just use SMO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got SMO in the title of your question. Why not just use SMO for backup and restore?